# Error logging in via FTP script in KornShell

Tags: shell, unix, ftp, ksh

I am trying to FTP a file using a script in KornShell (ksh) and I am getting a login failed message. I can login manually just fine but when I try the automated script, it does not like the password portion of the login information.

**Here's my script:**

```
ftp -n ftp.stmp.com <<EOF
user quser pass Sky3s3ch
binary                                                      
hash
prompt
put chr*.dat
EOF
```

**And this is the error that I get:**

```
dns: /u04/lms/ora_shell/clients/STMP > LMS_STMP_ECHI_FTP.ksh
Not logged in.
Login failed.
Please login with USER and PASS.
Hash mark printing on (1024 bytes/hash mark).
Interactive mode off.
Please login with USER and PASS.
Please login with USER and PASS.
```

I would appreciate any help I can get in figuring this out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are many different ftp clients, but I'm not familiar with one that requires the word `pass` as part of a single line login like you are using. Try

```
ftp -n ftp.stmp.com <<EOF
user quser Sky3s3ch
. . .
EOF
```

Another common form is to move the hostname inside the ftp input stream, i.e.

```
ftp -in  <<EOF
open ftp.stmp.com
quser Sky3s3ch
. . .
EOF
```

I don't have my sample code availab.e You may need `user` on the 2nd line of input, but I don't think so.

**Edit**
Finally, I noticed you have `put chr*.dat` in your input script. To transfer multiple files at the same time, you'll need the `mput` command instead.

I hope this helps.